# How to compile javascript files into one?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack, browserify

Let's say I have 2 files!

base.js

```
base = function(...) {
    ....
}
```

file1.js

```
base.function = function(.....) {
    ....
}
```

How could I compile them into a one file?
Does it require `requirejs`?
Does it require `nodejs`? Is there a documentation so that I learn that?

Thanks in advance overall!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it does not require `requirejs`

You can use browserify to compile all to one. It's just an example, what i use most. Webpack is used also.

You can find example code here (browserify combined with gulp):

https://github.com/liesislukas/ReactJs-ReactNative-examples/blob/master/examples/name-changer/gulpfile.js

and check around in same repository for more similar examples.

### webpack or browserify?

http://blog.namangoel.com/browserify-vs-webpack-js-drama

Comment: Well, I am testing it, telling you the results once finished, thanks for that!

Comment: Well, I succeeded creating my first project, thanks alot!

Comment: glad to hear such feedback! :))

Answer (score 2):

You can use grunt task runner which can concatenate files into one

Or any build tool such as gulp, webpack etc.

If you are looking for using require.js you can use r.js optimiser

Answer (score 0):

Using webpack is pretty simple. Let's say you have a webpack.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Then in your main.js file you can require other files, like this:

```
var file1 = require('./file2');
var file2 = require('./file2');
// ...
```

When you compile those files using webpack, you'd have only one file called bundle.js in the dist folder. This bundle.js file will have the content of the three files, main.js, file1.js, file2.js

For more information, on how to use Webpack you should [check its docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/), but this will do what you want.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but as far as I know you don't get 1 file and in this 1 file you can see all the code, the 1 file still references other files from the src directoy.